# Show current user location in Google Maps (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers

I want to be able to show the current user location, and to automatically put a pin where the user is located. I need this in HTML/JavaScript, full code. Please help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/loader/#ClientLocation

Comment: 'I need this in HTML/JavaScript, full code. Please help.' woah,I think you have misunderstood SO to be some other forum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use the Google API (JavaScript in this case) to show current location in maps. You've to import the library with:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer>
```

And use the function initMap:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: initLat, lng: initLon},
    zoom: 6
  });
```

When you obtain lat and lon from the navigation.geolocation, you've to update the map with map.setCenter(pos);, when pos is an array with lat and lon.

Here you've a full example.

[Google official doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

I hope it helps :-)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Hi i want to zoom the google maps. it is showing whole country and i want user location to have a blue dot.